# Is there a shorter way to write the below code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wondering if there is another shorter way to write the below code:

```
let playerListQuery = {
  variables = {
    input: {
      pagination,
      order: { field: PlayerOrderField.CreatedAtDesc },
      where: {
        // some others...
      },
    },
  }
};

function updateSearch(value) {
  if (!value) return;

  playerListQuery.variables = {
    ...playerListQuery.variables,
    input: {
      ...playerListQuery.variables.input,
      where: {
        ...playerListQuery.variables.input.where,
        or: [
          { nameContains: searchValue },
          {
            teamHas: [
              {
                or: [
                  { nameContains: searchValue },
                  { addressContains: searchValue },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };
}
```

As you can see I'm only interested to change the `where` field in `updateSearch`.

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a deep copy of your query then send the modified copy.

Something like so:

```js
function updateSearch(value) {
  if (!value) return;

  const newQuery = deepCopy(playerListQuery);
  newQuery.variables.input.where = { /* *** */ };
  return newQuery;
}
```

As for the function that does the deep copy, if your JS object is serializable, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))` is a quick and easy way to deep copy

If you have more complex needs, you could look into libraries (e.g.: lodash's `cloneDeep` function).